# Is there any specific setting for connecting to SQL Server through PHP on Linux CentOS 7

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, centos7, sqlsrv

I have already done this through Windows machine but getting error on Linux. I have been searching for the similar issues and implementing all I could get, but still no luck.

I am trying to connect SQL server on following environment:
Microsoft SQL Server 2016,
Linux Centos 7.9.2009,
PHP 7.3.29,
ODBC Driver 13 and 17

I have already install and enable the PDO_ODBC and pdo_sqlsrv, confirmed through phpinfo.

Below is my connection string:

```
$conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.99.237;Port:24115;Database=dbname;Uid=username;Pwd=password;")
```

also tried

```
$conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.99.237,24115;Database=dbname;", "username", "password")
```

and the error is

```
SQLSTATE[HYT00] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
```

Updated code and findings:

I am able to connect via cli:

```
isql MSSQL username password
```

```
tsql -S MSSQL -U 'username' -P 'password'
```

```
osql -S mssql -U username -P password
```

While trying through below PHP connection string, getting 'could not find driver'

```
new PDO("dblib:host=mssql;dbname=database", "username", "password");
```

Comment: What exact error do you get?

Comment: _To specify a non-standard TCP port, enter a comma after the server name or IP address, then enter the port number._ Have you tried what the docs recommend?

Comment: Obviously you are encountering an error when you attempt to connect. For future reference, post the complete error message - all of it. No one should have to guess that you did, in fact, encounter an error nor what that actual message was. Phrases like "having difficulty" and "no luck" are not useful things to post.

Comment: @SMor I have included error in my question.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes I have tried that combination too, but it didn't work.